# (How) should I flag an answer that links to a self-written external package to solve the question's problem?

Tags: support, flags, specific-answer, self-promotion

(How) should I [flag this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269702/4099598)?

> I wrote angular-server-repeat to (partially) solve this problem. Check it out.

It's not exactly NAA, since it does specify a package name to search for if the link rots. It's not spam, since it's not deceptive. It's not even necessarily VLQ, since it does seem to have some potential use. It's just that the answer can only be expressed as "I wrote up a whole ton of code which is far too large to include here, so here's the info to download it."

Maybe that would justify a vote/flag to close the *question* as too broad, except that it seems possible in general to answer without that.

I'm confused, is what I'm getting at.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Limits for self promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the poster:

1. Created today.
2. Spammed identical promotions for that thing into three questions within a minute or three (even if he says that's his, that's not enough).
3. Didn't do anything else.

By the way, the repo was set up in January.

That merits SPAM-Flags.
If you are unsure, at least flag "Other", and mention it to the mods, who will at the very least give that poster a stern talking-to.
Or if you are really unsure, ask here.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I guess I could have done some more due diligence on the poster and found that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Flag it as very low quality, it will drop in to the VLQ review where other users will vote to delete it as a link only answer.

When this happens the user who posted it will get an automated comment that says:

> “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”